# JSON time compare sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

JS

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $date = date('Gi', time());
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".show_hide").click( function()
       {
        var locTime = <?php echo json_encode($date) ?>;

$.getJSON( "url_to_json", function(data) {

    xr_mon_b_o = data.location.monday[0].b_o;
    xr_mon_l_c = data.location.monday[0].l_c;
    xr_mon_d_o = data.location.monday[0].d_o;
    xr_mon_d_c = data.location.monday[0].d_c;
    console.log("sucess1");
    if (locTime < xr_mon_b_o){
        console.log("sucess2");
        $('.xr').hide("drop", { direction: "down" }, 400); 
        }

    else if ( xr_mon_d_o < locTime > xr_mon_l_c){
        console.log("sucess4");
        $('.xr').hide("drop", { direction: "down" }, 400);
        }

    else if ( locTime > xr_mon_d_c){
        console.log("sucess4");
        $('.xr').hide("drop", { direction: "down" }, 400);
        }

        else {
        $('.s_lo').show("drop", {
              direction: "up"
          }, 800);
        }

});
       }
  );
});
```

jSON

```
{ "location": 
{
    "monday": [
    {"b_o": 700},
    {"l_c": 1400},
    {"d_o": 1700},
    {"d_c": 2100}

    ]
}
}
```

b = breakfast

l = lunch

d = dinner

o = open

c = close

I'm trying to make this script to work where the time falls into the else if arugement and trigger the closed location div to hide via jquery action. But somehow how the logic in this script doesn't seems to work quiet well. it worked fine with 1 if, but as i add more 'else if' the script falls apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is somewhat complicated. Here is the strategy I'd follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".show_hide").click(function(){
        var current_time = <?php echo intval($date) ?>;

        $.getJSON("url_to_json",function(data){
            /**
             * Assume the array is always ordered
             */
            var day = data.location.monday[0],
            time_diff = 2400, // Time difference between a shift, and now
            current_diff, // Auxiliar variable
            current_shift; // The current shift

            /**
             * Compare all shifts
             */
            for (shift in day) {
                /**
                 * If current time is exactly the same
                 * as the shift, we found the shift
                 */
                if (current_time == day[shift]) {
                    time_diff = current_diff;
                    current_shift = shift;
                    break;
                }
                else if (current_time > day[shift]) {
                    /**
                     * Calculate the time difference
                     */
                    current_diff = current_time - day[shift];

                    /**
                     * The shift with the minor time difference
                     * is the active shift
                     */
                    if (current_diff < time_diff) {
                        time_diff = current_diff;
                        current_shift = shift;
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * shift is now determined, think what to do
             * based on shift letters:
             *
             * (b|l|d)_(o|c)
             */
            if (shift.match(/b_/)) {
                // Breakfast
                if (shift.match(/_o/)) {
                    // Open
                }
                else {
                    // Closed
                }
            }
            else if (shift.match(/l_/)) {
                // Lunch
            }
            else {
                // Dinner
            }
        });
    });
});
```